# How can I tell which column is matching in a multi column FTS CONTAINSTABLE search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

In a full text search using something like ConstainsTable(tablename,*,'"lol"'), can I get back the name of the matching column for/with each result?

Answer (score 0):

Full-text doesn't support retrieving the column information using any of the CONTAINS{TABLE} / FREETEXT{TABLE} queries.

You could run [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607.aspx) on the indexed table and extract the column information for the search keyword (parse it with [sys.dm_fts_parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) when using a search phrase to eliminate stopwords).